# AVAudioPlayer cannot play music with a NSTimer in background

Tags: iphone, ios4, background, nstimer, avaudioplayer

I want to play music with an AVAudioPlayer using an NSTimer, but `[player prepareToPlay]` returns NO & doesn't play in the background.

Can somebody give me some idea?

Here's my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(playMusic:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)playMusic:(NSTimer *)timer{
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    NSString *fileName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Apologize.mp3"];
    NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName];
    NSError *error;
    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl error:&error];
    if ([player prepareToPlay]) {
        [player play];
        NSLog(@"start!");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"error msg ：%@",error);
    }
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents)]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    }

    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    //        /* just fail if this happens. */
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this init in the **viewDidLoad** :

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test"
                                                          ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL
                                                          error:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

This is for the audio initialization. Here, with a MP3 named *test*, imported in the project.
Note that the **beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents** part is very important. Without it, you cannot start playing from background, just keep on listening to music already playing from foreground.

Now you need to listen to the event **didEnterInBackGround** (you could go with the **applicationDidEnterBackground** of your app delegate, but this way you can put the code in the class it belongs to):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(didEnterBG:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

And now in that **didEnterBG** method :

```
self.backgroundTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(backgroundWork) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[self.backgroundTimer fire];
```

Here i make this sound repeat every 10s for personal reasons, but do whatever you need.
Finally, the **backgroundWork** method :

```
- (void)backgroundWork{
    [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.audioPlayer play];
}
```

Now your audio file is playing in background :-)

You should also note that your app need to have specific rights to keep doing jobs in background. You need to check the box under 'YourTarget' -> Capabilities -> Background Modes : Audio and AirPlay. Otherwise, the OS will terminate you app in a few minutes in real conditions (with no debugger or instrument).

Comment: This is really helpful but what If I want to start the sound ONLY in background mode? because using [self.backgroundTimer fire] will call backgroundWork and the app will play the sound

Comment: Well, as the background work function is called on `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`, the sound is only played when the app did actually enter in background mode.

Answer (score 0):

before going to code. you need to tell the OS that you want permission to play music in background.
you can do that by setting a Key in your app's info.plist

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
            <string>audio</string>
    </array>
```

doing so, you will be able to play audio when app moves to background.

Comment: but when i start a music in app ,it can play in background...
that drive me crazy for a long time...>_<

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but I found the solution from this post: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1668/_index.html

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];
if (setCategoryError) { /* handle the error condition */ }

NSError *activationError = nil;
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];
if (activationError) { /* handle the error condition */ }
```