# Background location alert with vibration?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, iphone-vibrate

I tried to use the method

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
```

to trigger vibration when the method

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
}
```

is called.

However, I found that the vibration never be triggered unless the app is at the foreground.

Any method to do this?

Comment: are you add the #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h> framework

Comment: of coz already import all necessary lib. It works when the app is at the foreground.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351815/start-playing-sound-in-background-on-ios